# Running scala/sbt from command line when it's installed through IntelliJ

Tags: windows, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

So far I have only been using Scala and SBT through IntelliJ. But when I try to run the scala or sbt commands in the windows command prompt, it says they can't be found. 
What's the easiest way of running the commands through the console, installing another separate scala installation? adding the intellij scala version to my path?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download scala/sbt in a separated path.(Do not install it.)
2. Adding the path in the ENV variable.